# environment variable used with gradle intellij - spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle

I am building a Spring Boot Java application using the lattest version of IntelliJ built with gradle on Windows 7. 
I am trying to leverage environment variables in my application.properties, one way I was able to get this functionality to work was to take the followimg steps. 
If I change over from gradle to maven I am able to simply leverage the Environment Variable under the menus Run -> Edit Configurations.

Please let me know why this process does not work for gradle and if the below process is recommended.

from application.properties

```
MyApplication.log_level = ${LOG_LEVEL}
```

from build.gradle

```
setEnvVarRunConfiguration 'MyApplication', 'LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'

def setEnvVarRunConfiguration( final String configuration, final String envName, final String envValue ) {
  final javaExecRunConfiguration = { task -> task instanceof JavaExec && task.name == "run $configuration" }
  tasks.matching(javaExecRunConfiguration).all { environment envName, envValue }
}
```

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-180652 may be the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

File -> Setttings -> Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle Runner

Ensure the checkbox "Delegate IDE build/run action to gradle" is unchecked

Comment: Might want to flesh this out, but I don't know why it got downvotes. It fixed this issue for me.

Comment: What is the updated version of this option ?